# EC2 temporary Key pair

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 production server running and i have a key.

Now we have some developers that need access to the server, but for security reasons i don't want to share our private key to the server because we will loose track of who has access to the server.

I have searched in amazons documentation for answers to this, but i can't find any solution there, i have also searched the stack overflow but can't find much other than people who lost there key pair.

Is there any way to make a temporary key for the EC2 instance? or any other way i can grant them temporary access to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same account cannot be shared by using different keys. The only way to give access is to create a new user and a new keypair. Once you decide the access has to be revoked, you have to delete that user. Adding and deleting an user is explained here: [Managing User Accounts on Your Linux Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Keypairs** are used to grant access to Amazon EC2 instances. They are public/private keypairs, typically randomly generated by EC2 but existing keypairs (or more specifically, the public half of the keypair) can be imported into EC2.

They are used as follows:

- **Windows:** When starting Windows from a standard Windows AMI, a utility called **Ec2Config** randomly generates an Administrator password, encrypts it using the public half of the keypair, and passes it back through the System Log. Users must decrypt it using their private key. They can then login to Windows.
- **Linux:** When starting Linux from a standard Linux AMI, the public half of the keypair is copied to `.ssh/authorized_keys`. Users can login via `ssh` by providing their private key.

(The reference to a 'standard' AMI is intentional -- AMIs created by other people will not necessarily have these utilities installed.)

In both situations, it is advisable that users then modify their instance to **use their normal security standards**. For example, Windows users should change the Administrator password, create additional users or, preferably, attach the instance to an Active Directory domain. Linux users should create additional users and install their standard keypairs in the `authorized_keys` file.

There should be no continuing need to use keypairs after the initial launch of the EC2 instance. Users should be using their own Username and password/keypair. It is not good practice to keep using the same password/keypair as initially created when the instance is launched.

Just think of the Amazon EC2 server as a "normal" server. What security would you normally put on a server to ensure that authorized users can login, but unauthorized users cannot? Go ahead and do the same thing with EC2.